# What is the best way to collapse and expand lists in html 4 using either CSS or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list within a list within a list, the outer list is a section , the next groups items with the same letter, and the third is the items themselves. I want to be able to close/open these lists, I've made a couple of attempts including one shown in the code below using a style but I cannot get anything to work.

There seem to be various ways to do this, but what is the definitive way to do this. I don't mind using css or javascript, I could even convert the document to html5 if there is an easy way to do it in there. The solution needs to work with recent version of the main browsers, I'm not worried about older browser versions.

This is what I currently have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="songkong.css">
        <base target="main">
        <style type="text/css">
            .row {
                vertical-align: top;
                height:auto !important;
            }
            .list {
                display:none;
            }
            .show {
                display: none;
            }
            .hide:target + .show {
                display: inline;
            }
            .hide:target {
                display: none;
            }
            .hide:target ~ .list {
                display:inline;
            }
            @media print {
                .hide, .show {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
         <h1>Sections</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_summary.html#Summary">Summary</a>
            </li>
            <li>MusicBrainz Summary
                <ul>
                    <li>D
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Daniel Desnoyers.html">Daniel Desnoyers</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_David Guetta.html">David Guetta</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Dev Electric.html">Dev Electric</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Diddy - Dirty Money.html">Diddy - Dirty Money</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Drake.html">Drake</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>E
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_E-40.html">E-40</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Eagles.html">Eagles</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Ed Sheeran.html">Ed Sheeran</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Elton John.html">Elton John</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Eminem.html">Eminem</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Enrique Iglesias.html">Enrique Iglesias</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Attempt with Accordian**

After changing from using lists to using headings for the outer layer I have managed to get it working for letters with the Musicbrainz summary, but when I repeat for sections within the Discogs summary it has no effect, **can I only use Accordian once within a file ?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="songkong.css">
<base target="main">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content"
});
});
</script></head>
<body>
<h1>Sections</h1>
<h2><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_summary.html#Summary">Summary</a></h2>
<h2>MusicBrainz Summary</h2>
<div id="accordion">
<h3>H</h3>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_musicbrainz_Hans Zimmer.html">Hans Zimmer</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3>T</h3>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_musicbrainz_The Zombies.html">The Zombies</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<h2>Discogs Summary</h2>
<div id="accordion">
<h3>H</h3>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_discogs_Hans Zimmer.html">Hans Zimmer</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you go through jqueryui documentation for Accordion or atleat the toggle method of Jquery?

Comment: Which versions of IE do you wish to support?

Comment: I'm pretty certain the easiest way would be with jQuery. I'm afraid I can't give an example though.

Comment: Try one of those methods you found and come back when they break. That's when you should ask.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ this might help .

Comment: yep, jquery, angular can be interesting too by using nested directives.

Comment: I did try one, see the <style> part emebedded in the html and it didnt work

Comment: I'm not a html developer, and my problem is that with all these methods I dont really understand what they are trying to do, I cant work out which is a good way and which is a bad way

Comment: The latest version of IE, Chrome and Firefox should suffice

Comment: @kaushikgandhi Accordian looks quite nice ,and I sort of got it working. It worked for one section but I couldnt gte it to work for a subsequent section, can it only be used once within a html file.

Comment: Comment on put on hold, whilst 'what is best' is opinion based, an opinion based on experience is lot more useful to me then having to try and find a solution with no good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using jQuery

Demo : http://jsbin.com/iZOsaVU/1/

```
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<h1>Sections</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_summary.html#Summary">Summary</a></li>
  <li id='li1'>MusicBrainz Summary</li>
  <div id='ct'>
  <ul id='ul1'>
<li id="l1-1">D
<ul id='ul1-1-1'>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Daniel Desnoyers.html">Daniel Desnoyers</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_David Guetta.html">David Guetta</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Dev Electric.html">Dev Electric</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Diddy - Dirty Money.html">Diddy - Dirty Money</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Drake.html">Drake</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>E
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_E-40.html">E-40</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Eagles.html">Eagles</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Ed Sheeran.html">Ed Sheeran</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Elton John.html">Elton John</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Eminem.html">Eminem</a></li>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00022_2013-09-01-10-16-49_musicbrainz_Enrique Iglesias.html">Enrique Iglesias</a></li>
  </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </ul>
```

jQuery: You can use same trick for other list items as well.

```
$("#li1").click(function(){
  $("#ct").toggle("fold",1000);
});
```

Explanation : http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/creating-tree-view-in-jquery/

Using Accordion

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible:true

});
$( "#accordion1" ).accordion({
heightStyle: "content",
  collapsible:true
});
```

HTML

```
  <h1>Sections</h1>
<h2><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_summary.html#Summary">Summary</a></h2>
<h2>MusicBrainz Summary</h2>
<div id="accordion">
<h3>H</h3>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_musicbrainz_Hans Zimmer.html">Hans Zimmer</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3>T</h3>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_musicbrainz_The Zombies.html">The Zombies</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<h2>Discogs Summary</h2>
<div id="accordion1">
<h3>H</h3>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="FixSongsReport_00042_2013-09-01-18-44-47_discogs_Hans Zimmer.html">Hans Zimmer</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the example but I must confess at first I ddint think it worked as thee is no visual cue to indicate you can collapse sections, and as it is you only seem able to collapse the Musicbrainz section not the D and E sections within it. Also I don;t really understand how it works some explanation would be useful

Comment: @PaulTaylor Check the explanation link.

Comment: thanks but still didnt make much sense, I'm trying to use Accordian instead which seems a bit more polished

Comment: You can have any number of Accordion on a page. It is mandatory to have one Div and heading for accordion to work. Read here http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/jquery-ui-demystified-part-1/

Comment: can you see what is wrong with my posted page above then because it is only working for the Musicbrainz part not the Discogs part

Comment: Your HTML is wrong.. ID should be unique.

Comment: thought it was something like that, but didnt know how to solve it, thanks I think Ill use Accordian and have marked your answer correct.